# Confirmar Codigo e passar para pagina de login

Tags: php, sql

Amigos sou novo em PHP + sql me ajudem aqui :

---

```
  --
-- Estrutura da tabela `verified_user`
--

 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `verified_user` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `email` text NOT NULL,
  `password` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
 -- Estrutura da tabela `verify`
--

 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `verify` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` text NOT NULL,
  `password` text NOT NULL,
 `code` text NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=29 ;
```

A PArtir da Tabela acima estou fazendo a chamada abaixo para tentar pegar o codigo cadastrado `code` correspondente,  validar , uma vez validado redireciono o usuario para outra pagina  index2.php   ,,, como posso fazer isso de forma simples no php ?  me ajudem se puderem

```
 <form method="post" action="verification.php">
 <input type="text" name="email">
 <input type="password" name="code">
 <input type="submit" name="register" Value="Register">
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crie uma página chamada "verification.php" e coloque o código abaixo. Ele vai conectar no seu Banco e vai selecionar os dados cadastrados no banco. Troque ali a linha do mysql_select_db e altere o 'nome_do_banco' para o nome do seu banco. não esqueça de deixar entre aspas

```
<?php
//Forma simples
$server = mysql_connect('localhost',root,'');
if($server){
    $banco = mysql_select_db('nome_do_seu_banco');
}
//CAPTURA OS DADOS INFORMADOS NO FORMULÁRIO
$email = $_POST['email'];
$code = $_POST['code'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM verify WHERE email = '$email' and code = '$code'" ;
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$total = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($total>0){
    //SE ENTROU AQUI, SINAL DE QUE FOI ENCONTRADO 1 REGISTRO PELO MENOS COM O EMAIL E CODIGO DIGITADOS
    //E SE ENCONTROU, SINAL QUE DIGITOU CERTO
    // AI CRIA A SESSÃO E VAI PRA SUA PAGINA;
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    header("location: index2.php"); 
}else{
    //SE ENTROU AQUI, DADOS INCORRETOS, VOLTA PRA PAGINA INDEX
    header("location: index.php");

}

?>
```

Comment: obrigado amigo,  me voltou o erro nas seguintes linhas , poderia me orientar ?                                                                                                       Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user 'nobody'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/west/public_html/consulta/confirma.php on line 40

Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/west/public_html/consulta/confirma.php on line 40

Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/west/public_html/consulta/confirma.php on line 41

Comment: $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $total = mysql_num_rows($result);

Comment: resolvi aqui amigo muito obrigado